# question related to array

Tags: php

I'm reading this format data from excel file. then I convert it into array. 
Now I want to perform calculation. I tried many times but no success. thanks

```
example
L*M    100*200
L*H    100*300

 0           1      2
 UserData       
 Length 100      L
 Width  200       W
 Height 300      H
 AdminData      
 L*W    Result  
 L*H    Result  
 W*H    Result  
 Total  TotalRest
```

Array result using print_r()

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => UserData
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Length
        [1] => 100
        [2] => L
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Width
        [1] => 200
        [2] => W
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Height
        [1] => 300
        [2] => H
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => AdminData
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => L*M
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => L*H
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => W*H
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Total
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )
```

)

Array function

```
$arrResult = array();

 /////////////Open the csv file which contains data//////////////

$handle = fopen("data.csv", "r");
if( $handle ) {
///////Put the data in an array///////////
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {      
$arrResult[] = $data;
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to add your question.

Comment: can you add your array please

Comment: not sure what you're aiming to do.  I guess that array isnt the way you want it?  you should share your desired results, and the code you are currently trying.  also, you'll probably have an easier time reading a CSV file, you can save excel spreadsheets to CSV easily

Comment: @ experimentX code is updated

Answer (score 0):

```
$var  = array(

    array('UserData'),

    array('Length', 100, 'L'),

    array('Width', 200, 'W'),

    array('Height', 300, 'H'),

    array('AdminData'),

    array('L*W'),

    array('L*H'),

    array('W*H'),

    array('Total')
    );

echo "<pre>"; 

print_r($var);

echo "</pre>";

$var[5][1] = $var[1][1]*$var[2][1];

$var[6][1] = $var[1][1]*$var[3][1];

$var[7][1] = $var[3][1]*$var[2][1];

echo "<pre>"; 

print_r($var);

echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks but it is possible with loop. because if user add more AdminData or add more userdata. thanks anyway

Comment: @user449744 then you have to user loop `for($i=0;$i<=$somval; $i=$i+7)` and $i+5 for 5, $i+6 for 6 and so on and on